# Error 'Class undefined: Zend_Cache' when install Magento on HHVM and Nginx

Tags: magento, hhvm, zend-cache

I want to install Magento 1.9.2.1 on my server with Nginx, HHVM & MySQL.

I managed to install & configure Nginx, HHVM & MySQL to work. With the latest source code of Magento version 1.9.2.1, I put it in the root folder of my site, then access the domain to start installing Magento as usual.

The problem is when I go to the site, it's blank instead of redirecting to the installation process.

Checking the error log in /var/log/hhvm/error.log, there is an error:

> Fatal error: Class undefined: Zend_Cache in
>   /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 137

Normally I think it should be included automatically by autoloading?

Comment: Why do you want to use HHVM ? It is not recommended by Magento.Try with Php 5.5

Comment: Similar to [This question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40248/magento-fatal-error-class-zend-cache-not-found)